# Unable to change height in javascript however can change width

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a website in HTML/PHP. I want the images to be different sizes depending on if your viewing on a mobile or PC. Weird part is on one of my pages both properties update the image on the screen when I type into the console, I forgot to add footer image related to pages that use the same image as a footer with the id `footerimage`.

Here is the HTML

```
<body onload="detectClient()">
    <header class="w3-display-container w3-content w3-wide" style="max-width:1500px;" id="home">
        <img class="w3-image" src="img/Websitebackground.png" alt="logo" width="1500" height="1000" id="headerimage">
    </header>
    ...
```

and here is the javascript:

```
function detectClient() {
    if ( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ){ 
      console.log(navigator.userAgent);
      document.getElementById("footerimage").width = "1500";
      document.getElementById("footerimage").height = "1000";
    } else { 
      console.log(navigator.userAgent);
      document.getElementById("headerimage").style.width = "1500";
      document.getElementById("headerimage").style.height = "450";
      console.log(console.error());
      console.log(document.getElementById("headerimage").height)
```

The console logging is for me to see in console if that code is executing correctly. I have thrown a jsfiddle together should work okay.
https://jsfiddle.net/9frpzy0k/

Comment: What is PHP part of this question?

Comment: I have this code in a few different pages and a few of those are PHP although I can see why I shouldn't of I shall remove that tag if I can

Comment: Quite possible, but problem you described didn't mention even any single PHP line, therefore I removed [tag:PHP] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the reason for no using jQuery nowadays? Some things works better and probably in future you'll find also other advantages. Note I didn't verify if your `if` statement works for mobile.

On the other hand. resizing image doesn't crop it, but just resizes, which may look kinda ... weird. Instead, I suggest using background image that fits the `div` container using vanilla CSS. Using this approach you can simulate `crop` solution with pure CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<header class="w3-display-container w3-content w3-wide" style="max-width:1500px;" id="home">
    <img class="w3-image" src="https://placem.at/things?w=1500&h=1000&random=image_1&txt=Image+1500+1000" alt="logo" width="1500" height="1000" id="headerimage">
</header>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let $headerImage = jQuery('#headerimage');

        if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            console.log(navigator.userAgent, 'mini');
            $headerImage.width(1500);
            $headerImage.height(1000);
        } else {
            console.log(navigator.userAgent, 'else statement');
            $headerImage.width(1500);
            $headerImage.height(450);
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

***post scriptum***

Also this should work in your code

```js
let img = document.getElementById("headerimage");

img.style.width = '1500px';
img.style.height = '450px';
```

or

```js
img.width = 1500;
img.height = 450;
```

Comment: The issue with the last part is both of them codes weren't changing the image displayed on the page only the width ones worked still the jquery example worked like a charm

Comment: I tested all variants and they do work. However maybe you have some conflict in you other JS you didn't show us and didn't realize that may conflict, such things happens in JS.